# Re-publish my webapp to Google Workspace Marketplace

Tags: google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

I received an email from Google saying that my webapp ([www.Photopea.com](http://www.Photopea.com)) is unpublished from the Google Workspace Marketplace, because I did not provide a privacy policy URL.

According to their web, Photopea has been installed 1.352 million times and many people are [complaining to me](https://twitter.com/InformaticoSAI/status/1526949647725613056) that they can not find it in the marketplace.

When I go to "Google Console" - "Photopea" - "APIs and services" - "Google Workspace Marketplace SDK" - "Store Listing", I see "Unpublished (Rejected)". The "PUBLISH" button is gray and says "Currently disabled.".

Is there a way to publish it again?

*** I don't know what "Google Workspace" is, I am not aware of ever using it. My only goal is to let people double-click PSD files in their Google Drive to edit them in Photopea. It worked perfectly [since 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7kjmwhlNrA) until now.

Comment: Have you tried to update the web app recently? It seems like Google reviewed your app and rejected it for some reason. If that's the case, you should have received a message at the email provided at `Google Workspace Marketplace SDK` under `App Configuration -> Developer Email`.

Comment: I received an email telling me to resubmit by app for a review. But I don't know how :( https://i.imgur.com/fkZCsvl.png

Comment: How did you first submit your app? If you visit the `Store listing` tab at `Google Workspace Marketplace SDK` in your project, can you see a `Publish` or `Unpublish` button at the bottom? Check https://developers.google.com/workspace/marketplace/how-to-publish